# Problem with url-rewriting for a multi-language website

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I have tried to set somes url rewriting rules for my multi-langage website.
It was working, and I wanted to apply some corrections, and now it is not working anymore.

When I tried this url : http://mywebsite.fr/fr/ , the browser changes the url for http://mywebsite.fr/fr/?lang=fr&lang=fr&lang=fr&lang=fr&lang=fr&lang=fr&lang=fr&lang=fr&lang=fr&lang=fr&lang=fr&lang=fr&lang=fr&lang=fr&lang=fr&lang=fr&lang=fr&lang=fr

Here is the code:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(fr|en|nl)/$ index.php?lang=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

I said to myself that kind of bug couldn't come from url-writing, so in my php code I have put an "return false" as the very beginning of the page, the problem still occurs whit a white page...

Also, if I disable all the url-rewriting rules, I recevied an apache error "Not found"...

I have also tried to restart Apache, same problem...

Anybody have an idea ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

What you see is a *typical* rewrite loop. The cause is that you unconditionally rewrite, regardless whether the goal of rewriting has already been achieved, so whether rewriting has already been performed before.

You can get around that using a condition:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^lang=
RewriteRule ^/?(fr|en|nl)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks of your reply, but it is not working. Now I have an apache error "Not found" and it continues to rediect to the url with the loop....

Comment: Not found? That indicates that you do not have a ``index.php`` routing script?

Comment: Yes I have a index.php file. Now it has the same behaviour that there is no url-rewrting rules... It says: "Not Found

The requested URL /fr/ was not found on this server."

Comment: The problem is still there, but now when I try the url  http://mywebsite.fr/fr/, there is no loop, but as soon as I clicked on a link, I have an apache "Not found" error and the loop appers on the URL.

Comment: Sounds like the framework you implement in the `index.php` only hands out relative references. That means that you final URLs you "click on" point to something like `http://mywebsite.fr/fr/...` which I dare say is _not_ what you want. In your question you specifically started of with an internal rewriting, maybe you instead actually want an _external redirection_ ? So something like `RewriteRule ^/?(fr|en|nl)/?$ /index.php?lang=$1 [R=302,QSA]` ? Take care to store the language choice in your session then, though...

Comment: All the links of the website redirect to an url like http://mywebsite.fr/fr/#!my-page-234564. And the URL rewriting should transforme the "fr/" part to ?lang=fr. Now I am almost sure that the problem do not come from the url rewriting, I keep searching...

Comment: OK, so you _do_ want to keep the `/fr/` prefix as part of _all_ references within your application? Sure, possible, in that case the internal rewriting as shown in the answer should be fine. The loop might be the result of some component not considering the language setting now handed over as HTTP GET argument and keeps redirecting to some default language...

Comment: Finally I found it ! The problem comes from url without the urls without the "www". How can manage with the url rewrting to redirect the visitor to this url www.mywebsite.fr/fr if he tries  mywebsite.fr or  mywebsite.fr/fr ?

Comment: Keep separate things separate, as a rule of thumb. Here that means: implement a separate _external_ redirection rule _before_ your other rewriting rules that forwards requests to the "non www variant" of the host name to the "www variant". Note: an external redirection, not an internal rewrite. You will find endless examples for that here on SO.